# Combining multiple spreadsheet files in to one master overview (read only)

Tags: google-sheets

Let me start by saying that I know too little about coding etc to translate some of the solutions given on this platform to solve my issue. So hopefully someone can help me get started..

I am trying to combine a certain section of multiple google spreadsheet files with multiple tabs into one file. The name and number of the various tabs are different (and change over time).

To explain. We have for various person an overview of their projects (each project on its own tab). Each project/tab contains a number of to do's. What I need to achieve is to import al the to do's to a master list so that we have 1 master overview (basically a big to do list that I can sort on date).

Two exmples with dummy information.  The relevant information starts on line 79
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FsQd9sKaAG7hKynVIR3sxqx6_yR2_hCMQWAWsOr4tj0/edit?usp=sharing
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/155J24uQpRC7uGvZEhQdkiSBnYU28iodAn-zR7rUhg1o/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Since this information is dynamic and you are restricted from using app script, you can create a "definitions" or "parameters" sheet where the person must either report the NAMES of their projects and the ROW the tasks starts on and total length. From there you can use importrange function to get their definitions. From the definitions you can use other import range functions to get their tasks list. Concatenating it is gonna be a pretty big issue for you though.

This unfortunately would be much easier for you to accomplish with a different architecture to your docs / sheets. The more a spreadsheet looks like a database (column heads and rows of data that match those headers), the easier they are to work with. The more they look like forms / paper worksheets the more code you would need to parse that format.